# Objective-C - how to do exception catch and avoid to have app crash?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

When i call this function few times from my button (like mad more then few times), then my app crash instead of just throw exception and ignore.

How do you ignore to crash when exception happened?

where localView is `UIView *localView`.

```
- (void)smallLocalView {
  @try {
    self.localView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.localView.layer removeFromSuperlayer];
      //self.localView.opaque = NO;
  }
  @catch(NSException *exp) {
      //NSLog(@">>> failed %@" , exp.reason);
    NSLog(@"OK - but dont crash!!!");
  }
  @finally {
    NSLog(@"OK - but dont crash!!!");
  }

}
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: in general you can't catch access violation, in this particular case you can add check for `self.localView != nil`

Comment: I applied !=nil but still same crash.

Comment: hmm, ok, crash can happen when `self` or `localView` (or both) is null, please update code and line when it crashes now

Comment: check my EDIT please.

Comment: Don't - this is a terrible idea. Find out what the error is and fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are on the Main thread when changing the background color.

You can add an assert at the beginning, like this, other check the stack trace on the left side when you get the exception in order to check in which thread you're on:

```
NSAssert([NSThread isMainThread]);
```

Also, depending on where you are calling `smallLocalView` from, it might happen that your view is not loaded/ready.

```
- (void)smallLocalView {
    if (!self.isViewLoaded) {
      return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

tl;dr In general you shouldn't try to catch exceptions, you should try to fix the root cause.

There are two kinds of exception you are interested in. The first kind as shown in your image is a system exception. The processor has encountered a problem, for example trying to access protected memory (usually called by trying to dereference a null pointer). You cannot catch that kind of an exception. The operating system will terminate your program when one is raised.

The problem, by the way, is almost certainly caused by localView having been deallocated prematurely, or maybe you access it not on the main thread (as per Edgar's answer).

The other kind of exception is the Objective-C exception which is always raised programmatically. Although you can catch these with a `@try { ... } @catch { ... }` block, in general you should not. The reason is that there is no enforcement to make code exception safe, so the exception may unwind stack frames where resources need to be deallocated or stack frames where clean up is needed to keep data structures consistent. Once an exception is thrown and caught, you cannot guarantee the logical consistency of your program's state. Your only real option is to terminate as cleanly as possible.